# Client Side Edit function with BootStrap and MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, server-side

I hope I can make this simple enough.  I am working with a new developer on a project where we are using Bootstrap for the frontend and .NET MVC for the backend. One of the features I would like to implement this time around is "Edit on Demand", in english clicking the pencil next to a field and the usual field opens for "Edit"; the user then clicks to save. He is claiming that the coding process to implement such a feature cannot be rolled through out the entire application, and this will be a long and grueling to make all the Server Side Calls.

I am looking for a way to (if possible) to make the coding process quick and easy, along with the possibly to reuse through the application.  Can anyone add how they would approach this task? Also, I did find this option (https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html).  I am not sure if this "simplifies" development.

Comment: Are you implying editing a single field at a time or via the demo grid row -> Edit -> record to edit via modal popup. The sample grid + model edit of the row is fairly rudimentary MVC, so getting one going then just copy and paste and minor modifications for the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is perfectly doable. If you were planning on editing the fields anyway, you would have to provide a view for that, controller to handle the post data and then backend to handle the database updates.

You can post asynchronously to that same controller whenever the user carries out and edit. The textboxes or other fields for editing can easily be substitutes using Javascript. It's not really that much extra work to put this in place throughout the App, but that will depend on how involved your forms are. Bootstrap certainly provides a bunch of tool to make the UI easy, but not that much for handling posting asynchronously. I wasn't aware of the tables thing, but that certainly looks handy... if you have tables. Looks like for non-tabular forms you will have to do the work.

In any case it certainly will be extra work. Especially if you want to go the route of progressive enhancements and cater for users who might not have Javascript enabled...

If I were you I'd got and make the website without and then add the on-demand feature at the end if time permits it as it isn't critical.

Comment: Yu_ominae Thank you for the response and answer. So basically as I thought we will design without it and add later. Its a situation where I don't want to be doing double work, so if we add the function now does it make our lives easier.

Thank you again

Comment: In my experience it will help if you design the standard site with the fact in mind that you will add progressive enhancements later. Like you might hide UI elements you don't need to show in your on-demand version and it's better to design the layout with that in mind.
It's also a good idea to design your views in such a way that you can easily use them as partial views too if you want to inject them later.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you should try to put as much of the structure in place as you can of course, so as to make it easy later to add the rest. But I wouldn't get started on anything specific at this stage, and certainly not on any JS functions.
I guess you will have to get your colleague on board to have him agree to design the site with adding progressive enhancements later. That way you can get the UI and controllers sorted right from the start.